# What moves my paddle?

Tags: phaser-framework

I use the following code: It creates a paddle, and it is supposed to move when I move the mouse. But instead it vibrates all over the place.

I included a bit of the console.log at the end so you can see the result. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
var screenWidth = 800;
var screenHeight = 400;
// Create the state that will contain the whole game
var mainState = {  
    preload: function() {  
        game.load.image('paddle', 'assets/graphics/Paddle.png');
    },
    create: function() {  
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        game.world.enableBody = true;

        this.paddle = game.add.sprite(screenWidth/2 - 50, screenHeight - 50, 'paddle');
        this.paddle.body.immovable = true;
    },
    update: function() {  
        var testvalue = this.paddle.x;
        this.paddle.x = game.input.x;
        console.log(testvalue + " / " + this.paddle.x);
    },
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(screenWidth, screenHeight);  
game.state.add('main', mainState);  
game.state.start('main');
```

Console output: First number is the position of the paddle before I use this.paddle.x = game.input.x;

- 360 / 371
- 415 / 371
- 426 / 371
- 382 / 371
- ...

I have written nothing to manipulate `paddle.x` except that one statement. And the log proves that the statement is correct, but something else messes with the code. 
If I remove `this.paddle.x = game.input.x;`, the paddle stands still. and doesn't move.

If I remove: `game.world.enableBody = true;` it works, but then I get no physics

I tested it in all 3 major browsers. and I run it locally with Xampp

There is another example of it [here](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/games/breakout) but I get the same 'vibrating' paddle when I try it on my system. However it works fine on the website of phaser.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

> collisions rely on the object colliding having a velocity. If you're telling the object every frame what its x and y positions should be, then the object has no velocity to calculate, and collisions will not occur... or will occur but go crazy, depending how and when in the frame you do it. You need something more like the 'moveToPointer' code (which sets the velocity such that it moves to the pointer position) but only when the pointer is held down on the object, and somehow smooth out that weird vibrating/orbiting issue that happens when it reaches the pointer.

[Found the answer on html5gamedevs forum](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/7876-mouse-moves-track/)

So now I implemented the following

```
var diff =  game.input.x - this.paddle.x
this.paddle.body.velocity.x = diff*10;
```

Which works like a charm.